# How to change page's language?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, browser

It is possible to get the language: navigator.language
But is it possible to set it to something else?

The original problem is that on iOS device (ipad, iphone) the multiselect in the browser has "0 items" text when nothing is selected (and "n items" when > 1 item is selected).

I can't rely on the locale selected in the browser/system because the website itself has language selection box. And this multiselect label seems to be depending on the selected locale.

"lang" html5 attribute doesn't help.

Comment: *""lang" html5 attribute doesn't help."* Then I suspect either you're using it incorrectly (if you showed us what you'd tried, we might be able to help), or you should file a bug with Apple or whoever is showing the relevant text (are you sure it's iOS/Safari?), as [that's what it's for](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-lang).

Comment: I've always assumed that those kind of default texts in browser are dependent of the selected UI language of the browser or in this case iOS and can not be overridden by the web page or server.